# How to add relationship attributes in entity framework model first?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

How can I add a relationship attribute in a many to many relationship when I am using a model first approach with Entity framework?

Suppose I have two entities **Entity_1** and **Entity_2** which has a many to many association. Let's assume this association has an attribute *attr1*. How do I model this in the entity designer in visual studio 2013?

Is there any option to do it or isn't there any option?

Comment: Talk is cheap, show me the code.

Comment: There is no code. I am trying to implement the database  in the model first approach.

Comment: Attributes are a code-only construct.  If there's no code then there's no question.

Comment: Model first or code first?

Comment: Model first.. So does it mean that I cannot model many to many relationship attributes with model first

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything on the subject.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx